# changing UINavigationBar size raises problem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, uinavigationbar

[image]

I had changed the size of UINavigationBar by doing

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect frame = self.navigationBar.frame;
    frame.size.height = 44;
}
```

after doing landscape view, I got below problem.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just manually resize the Navigation Controller's View Controller's view.

Comment: can you give me hint how can I achieve your idea?